# Collapsed navigation bar title is unintentionally expanded to large title if any UI element is modified

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

To demonstrate the problem, I wrote a very simple demo app. If I scroll down on the scroll view, the navigation bar title collapses as desired. If the button on the bottom is pressed, the button image is changed. However, this also causes the navigation bar to show a large title again, which is not desired. The same problem also occurs if for example the visibility of a UI element is changed (button.isHidden = true), or if any other UI element is modified in a number of other ways.

Is there any possibility to avoid this undesired behaviour, i.e., for the title to remain in its collapsed state even if UI elements are modified?

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var buttonActivated = false
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }()
    
    let cardView1 : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        return view
    }()
    
    let cardView2 : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        return view
    }()
    
    let cardView3 : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        return view
    }()
    
    let cardView4 : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        return view
    }()
    
    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Test Button ", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.label, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.label
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(cardView1)
        scrollView.addSubview(cardView2)
        scrollView.addSubview(cardView3)
        scrollView.addSubview(cardView4)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            cardView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            cardView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            cardView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            cardView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            cardView3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView2.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            cardView3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            cardView4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView3.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            cardView4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            cardView4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardView4.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        
        ])
        
    }

    @objc private func buttonPressed() {
        
        if !buttonActivated {
            button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
        }
        
        buttonActivated = !buttonActivated
        
    }

}
```

[image]

Edit: The same problem is present if the UI change is performed from the main thread, e.g.:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"), for: .normal)
            }
```

Comment: Can't find this behaviour in iOS 15, I run your code in 15 works as expected. I have not migrated to 16, so can't test it.

Comment: Check this - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708156